# Global hashable attributes undefined in p5.js Instance Mode

Tags: javascript, p5.js

apparently `g.image` is considered to be undefined whilst `g.s4.w` and `g.s4.h` are not
despite the fact that they are all defined at the same level.

```
var g = {}
//g.* VARS

function setup() {
        //ALL THE OTHER g.* VARS
    g.w=int(windowWidth*0.95)
    g.h=int(windowHeight*0.95)
    g.viewDistance=int(g.w/6)
    g.widgetHeight=int(g.h*0.25)
    g.s1.w=g.w-2*g.viewDistance
    g.s1.h=g.widgetHeight
    g.s2.w=2*g.viewDistance
    g.s2.h=g.s1.h
    g.s3.w=g.s1.w
    g.s3.h=g.h-g.widgetHeight
    g.s4.w=g.s2.w
    g.s4.h=g.s3.h
    g.image = []


new p5(function (p1) {
  "use strict";

  p1.setup = function () {
    p1.createCanvas(g.s1.w, g.s1.h);
    //STUFF
  };

  p1.draw = function () {
                //THE VARS THAT AREN'T g.*
        for (var i=0;i<g.s4.w*g.s4.h;i++) {
            if (g.image[i]!=p1.color(0)){
                                  //STUFF
                }
            }
        }
  };
},
"sketch01");
```

I've cut it down to the important bits

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`
at the line `if (g.image[i]!=p1.color(0)){`

I'm asking for an explanation as to why this happens (and suggestions on how to fix it) more than I am asking for a workaround.

EDIT: It seems also that defining g.image inside of p1.setup() results in the same error.

Comment: Have you tried renaming it? I know that normal Processing uses an internal variable named `g` that might be conflicting with this variable.

Comment: I gave it a shot and no luck

Comment: Even defining g.image using loadPixels() in the same p1.draw loop prior doesn't work, however defining g.image to be [] does not throw an error (but that's certainly not what I want to be doing)

Comment: Bizzarely even when it's a completely new, local variable the same error exists. It seems that all arrays become undefined at some point in instance mode. Is this something wrong with my p5 installation?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] showing the problem with a local variable instead of a `g` variable?